# OnDestinationChangeListener does not work for activity destinations

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I am attaching an `OnDestinationChangedListener` to my `NavController` in my Activity.

It works fine for all fragment destinations. However when I navigate to an activity destination my listener is not notified of the change.

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    navFragment.findNavController().addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
        Log.e("Navigation", "id: ${destination.id} label: ${destination.label}")
    }
}
```

How can I listen destination changes for activity destinations as well?

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#add_a_navhost_to_an_activity) says, that:

> The Navigation component is designed for apps that have one main
>   activity with multiple fragment destinations. The main activity is
>   associated with a navigation graph and contains a NavHostFragment that
>   is responsible for swapping destinations as needed. In an app with
>   multiple activity destinations, each activity has its own navigation
>   graph.

So for now I think that you have to keep track on your activities by yourself. :-( Navigation graphs seem to be "encapsulated" inside exactly one activity.